# Calling parent move assignment operator when source object still needs to be used after

Tags: c++, inheritance, memory, move-semantics

**TLDR** - Feel free to mark this as a duplicate if it is so; I will delete the question. However, I couldn't find anything after looking around for a bit.

Consider the following classes:

```cpp
class Base
{
public:
    Base(std::string var1);

    Base& operator=(Base&& other) noexcept
    {
        if (this != &other)
            var1_ = std::move(other.var1_);
        return *this;
    }

protected:
    std::string var1_;
};

class Child final : public Base
{
public:
    Child(std::string var1, std::string var2);

    Child& operator=(Child&& other) noexcept
    {
        if (this != &other)
        {
            // Take note of HERE for explanation below
            Base::operator=(std::move(other));
            var2_ = std::move(other.var2_);
        }
    }

private:
    std::string var2_;
};
```

Here there are two classes, `Child` deriving from `Base`. `Child` has more members than `Base`. In the move assignment operator of `Child`, we have a situation where we have extra members that also need to be assigned to the values of `other`'s members. However, we're first moving the memory of `other` to the parent move assignment operator, so wouldn't that data then be unusable?

I suppose I'm simply confused on (1) if there's actually anything wrong with what I have above, (2) if so, why does it work since `other` is supposed to be moved before it is used, and (3) if not, what is the best way to accomplish the task I have?

Is the better way to do this simply to initialize the members of `Child` first and *then* hand it over to the `Base` move assignment operator? Does it make a difference?

Comment: I think you're mentally confusing values with variables.  You've moved the value of `var1_` from one object to the other, but the `var1_` variable still exists, and is still usable. It merely contains a "moved from" value, of some sort. What value it holds is irrelevant, because your `operator=` never reads from it after that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is safe.

First, note that the rule about not using a moved-from object is a default guideline for designing and using objects. It is not a rule of the language itself. It's the common practice for what class objects *generally* guarantee after they've been moved-from, including Standard Library class types that don't specify otherwise (like `std::unique_ptr<T>` guarantees a moved-from pointer holds a null pointer).

So since you know exactly what `Base::operator=` does to `other`, and that only moves from `other.var1_`, it's still safe to use `other.var2_`.

There's another reason this pattern is safe, even if you don't actually know precisely what `Base::operator=` does, or you want to write the `Child` code to keep working even if the details of `Base` change. A `Child` object contains two subobjects: the `Base` base class subobject and the `var2_` member subobject. These objects don't inherently know anything about the other. (They could have manually set-up interactions with each other via pointers, virtual functions, etc., to complicate things, but that sort of thing should be documented for `Base` or known in `Child`) The `Base::operator=(std::move(other));` statement moves from just the base class subobject, not from the member subobject, so the member subobject is not affected, and the definition of `Child::operator=(Child&&)` is safe against changes to `Base`.

Comment: I appreciate your thoroughness. I had a small question, though. You say "The `Base::operator=(other);` statement moves from just the base class subobject, not from the member subobject, so the member subobject is not affected ..." but my own code uses a move statement inside the function call (e.g. `Base::operator=(std::move(other))`). Would this affect anything you've already said?

Comment: @DrakeJohnson You might want to read the "Moving from lvalues" section of [this (rather long) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11540204/9837301) to "What is move semantics?" In particular, the expression `std::move(other)` does not "move memory".

Comment: No, nothing changes. The `Base` move assignment operator calls the `std::string` move assignment operator on the members of the two objects, yes. Which makes sure `this->var1_` has the string which was in `other.var1_`, and does whatever unpredictable things it wants to `other.var1_`, and that's it. `other.var1_` is even still a valid `std::string` object in absolutely every sense - you just shouldn't count on what its contents happen to be.